# Best way to read data from a file

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Best way to read a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)

In Java I can open a text file like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
```

My question is, how do you read from the following file? The first line is a number (830) representing number of words, and the following lines contain the words.

```
830  
cooking   
English  
weather  
.  
.
```

I want to read the words into a string array. But how do I read the data first?

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track; I would treat the first line as a special case by parsing it as an integer (see [`Integer#parseInt(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)) then reading the words as individual lines:

```java
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
String numLinesStr = reader.readLine();
if (numLinesStr == null) throw new Exception("invalid file format");
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
int numLines = Integer.parseInt(numLinesStr);
for (int i=0; i<numLines; i++) {
  lines.add(reader.readLine());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some special reason, it's not necessary to keep track of how many lines the file contain. Just use something like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with Java version greater than 1.5, you can also use the Scanner class:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("someTextFile.txt"));
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
int lines = sc.nextInt();

for(int i = 1; i <= lines; i++) {
    words.add(sc.nextLine());
}

String[] w = words.toArray(new String[]{});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the class java.io.BufferedReader, created on a java.io.FileReader.
This object has the method readLine, which will read the next line from the file:

```
try
{
    java.io.BufferedReader in = 
        new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader("filename.txt"));

    String str;
    while((str = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
        ...
    }
 }
 catch(java.io.IOException ex)
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection and do this dynamically:

```
 public static void read() {

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                        "filename.txt"));

                String line = reader.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    if (Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(line.getClass())) {
                        int number = Integer.parseInt(line);
                        System.out.println(number);
                    } else {
                        String word = line;
                        System.out.println(word);
                    }

                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```